# Dirac or Schrödinger equation for higher spin?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation, higher-spin

Given a fermion or boson with an arbitrary integer or half integer spin, then what would be its Dirac or Klein-Gordon equation?

Dirac equation for an equation with arbitrary spin 0, 1/2 , 1 , 2 , 3/2 , and so on

Also, if supersymmetry is correct, then what would be the relation of an equation of a particle with spin $d$ and its corresponding super partner with spin $d-1/2$?

Comment: for spin 3/2 it's called Rarita–Schwinger equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation. Dirac is the name for spin 1/2

Comment: Spin $n$ integer particles are represented by completely symmetric, traceless, trasverse tensor of rank $n$ which is obeyed KG equation. Spin $n+1/2$ half integer particles are represented by gamma-matrix traceless, completely symmetric, transverse tensor which carries $n$ vector indices and one Dirac spinor indice, which is obeyed Dirac equation (in spinor space).

Comment: Look for Gelfand-Yaglom equations. Similar analyses had been initially performed by Dirac, then by Pauli & Fierz.

Comment: To make them look like Dirac: Dirac-Kemmer-Petiau - particularly suited for non-zero rest mass (e.g. the Proca equations instead of the Maxwell equations). There is a simple transform that will turn any of the Lagrangians with quadratic kinetic terms into Lagrangians that look like Dirac. *Conversely* (!!) there is a simple transform that goes the other way around - though I think it only works for parity-symmetric Dirac Lagrangians; making the kinetic term quadratic like Klein-Gordon, Maxwell or Proca. I'll look into this and provide a more detailed answer - as an actual answer - later.

Answer (score 1):

Eqs of motion for arbitrary spin massive field are given in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227691/how-to-construct-fields-from-from-unitary-representation-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-group/227747#227747). Massless case can be also explocitly treated in a such way.

Briefly, equations of motion for field which represents the given elementary particle may be obtained from the statement that particles realizes unitary irreducible representations of Poincare group. As we know, for the irreducible representations Casimir operators acts as unity matrix, so by rewriting Casimir operators in differential form you obtain equations.