# Are electric and magnetic fields canonical conjugates?

Tags: electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, canonical-conjugation

When quantizing the electromagnetic fields in the context of quantum optics and quantum field theory, we often go for the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ and its canonical momentum, which turns out to be $\epsilon_0 \dot{\mathbf{A}} = -\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}$ in the absence of source charges. (By "go for" I mean we choose these to be the conjugate variables needed for quantization.) I understand this procedure well enough.

However, I have seen and been told that it's also possible to choose $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and quantize with these. An example is given in [these lecture slides](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_quant_em.pdf).

So my question is, are $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ canonical conjugates? If so, can you show this from the radiation Hamiltonian $$ \mathcal{H}_R = \frac{1}{2} \int \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf{B}^2\,dV $$ and Maxwell's equations? I was unable to do it when I tried.

If it is possible and all the formalism is right, then is there a situation where we would prefer one choice of variables over the other?

Comment: Your linked lectures *show* you they are, bottom of p15, and then optimizes the system by resolving it in canonically normalized normal oscillators! If you wanted the commutator of **E** and **B**, the explicit expressions at the bottom of p18 are staring you in the face. Just do it--assuming you understood the vector potential quantization and the normal mode decoupling. Show your work, as it is thoroughgoingly unclear what is blocking you.

Comment: Explicit field commutators in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451556/66086).